# Function takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given, but inspect.getsource shows a function definition with 2 parameters

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am getting the above error with a function that is defined to take 2 arguments on a Jupyter notebook in Sagemaker. What am I doing wrong?

```
import inspect
lines = inspect.getsource(create_unique_files_dict)
print(lines)
​
unique_files_dict = create_unique_files_dict('../data/detectron2_partial_3_columns_data', '.json')
dataset_files = create_train_test_val_dict(unique_files_dict, test_val_size=0.2)
```

Output of cell:

```
def create_unique_files_dict(data_path, extension):
    data_files = {}
    for class_folder in os.listdir(data_path):
        data_files[class_folder] = {}
        for file in os.listdir(f'{data_path}/{class_folder}'):
            # Remove the page indicator from the filename to determine unique files
            doc = re.sub(r'page_\d*', '', file)
            doc = doc.replace(extension, '')
            if '.ipynb' not in file:
                if doc not in data_files[class_folder]:
                    data_files[class_folder][doc] = []
                data_files[class_folder][doc].append(file)
    return data_files

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 5
      2 lines = inspect.getsource(create_unique_files_dict)
      3 print(lines)
----> 5 unique_files_dict = create_unique_files_dict('../data/detectron2_partial_3_columns_data', '.json')
      6 dataset_files = create_train_test_val_dict(unique_files_dict, test_val_size=0.2)
      7 print(dataset_files)

TypeError: create_unique_files_dict() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python inspect.getsource gets the wrong source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306489/python-inspect-getsource-gets-the-wrong-source)

Comment: To interpret the link above, `getsource` goes to the source file itself.  It's likely that you have changed the function in your notebook without saving the result, and the one you typed only takes one parameter.

Comment: I have no idea how the function could be different from what was printed there (since I ran the cell above which imports the function before I ran that cell), but restarting the kernel seemed to work.